# Python add time using variables

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I want to add hours and minutes to a time, using variables.  So, in the example below, instead of having 'hours=3, minutes=30', I would like to have 3 and 30 stored in variables.

Is this possible?

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
ahead_time = now + datetime.timedelta(hours=3,minutes=30)
print("  now time is ", now, " ahead_time is ", ahead_time)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, named (keywoard) arguments can have variables (well, any expression, really), same as any argument. Such a question can often be answered simply by trying it.

Comment: Replace `3` and `30` with the names of variables. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using command line you can write like below

```
import datetime
import argparse

def getTime(hour, minutes):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    ahead_time = now + datetime.timedelta(hours=int(hour),minutes=int(minutes))
    return "  now time is %s ahead_time is %s" %(now, ahead_time)

def parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process the input time.')
    parser.add_argument('--hour', dest='hour')
    parser.add_argument('--minutes', dest='minutes')
    return vars(parser.parse_args())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parser()
    hour = args.get('hour', None)
    minutes = args.get('minutes', None)
    if hour and minutes:
        print getTime(hour, minutes)
```

Usage:

```
$ python test.py --hour 3 --minutes 30
  now time is 2017-03-23 06:37:49.890000 ahead_time is 2017-03-23 10:07:49.890000
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I had tried to replace the numbers with variables, as suggested by others above, but your example showing to use of 'int' was what I was missing.  I really appreciate the helpful example.

Comment: @DonC Thank you.